# Why in C++ the output of integer variable of value 65536 is 0 and < 65536 gives a negative integer and > 65536 value gives a positive integer?

Tags: c++, c, integer, type-conversion, turbo-c

Why in Turbo C++ IDE the output of an integer variable of a hard coded value of 65536 is 0 and lesser than that value (65536) is a negative integer and greater than that value (65536) is a positive integer?

If we initialize an integer with a hard coded value of 65536 and print it, it will print 0 and if we change the value of that integer variable from 65536 to 65535 or lesser like 65534 and so on it prints -1,-2,... and if we change the value of that integer variable from 65536 to 65537 or greater it will print 1,2,3... and so on, why is this happening?
I verified it on Turbo C++ IDE.

Kindly explain the logic and working behind this clearly as I'm a beginner.

Comment: You should read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_%28computer_science%29  It would appear the int variable type is 16-bits in your chosen compiler which gives it a range of -32768 to 32767, or 0 to 65535 if unsigned.

Comment: `((x + 2^15) mod 2^16) - 2^15`

Comment: @MajidTaheri If you can spread the knowledge to someone who doesn't posses it already, that would not make you inferior.

Comment: He's a beginner, it isn't trivial for him.

Comment: Whoah, people still use TurboC++?  I think the last time I wrote something with that IDE was 15 years ago, and even *then* it was practically obsolete.  Hopefully you have the version that allowed more than one item in the "undo" history!! =)

Answer (score 7):

The ancient Turbo C++ used 16-bit `int`.

Answer (score 4):

It seems you are talking about 16-bit signed value (-32768 to 32767), it means that it treats left-most bit as sign.

If you put into it 65535 (1111 1111 1111 1111) - it will treat it as negative since left-most bit is 1. Other bits (all one's) give the greatest negative value which is equal '-1'. It will remain negative until left most bit become 0. It will be 32767.

If you put 65536 (0001 0000 0000 0000 0000) - it will just cut last 16 bit, which all is zero's, and this value will be equal '0'.

65538 (0001 0000 0000 0000 0010) - again will cut last 16 bits, and you will get '2'

Note: Generally speaking you must not save values out of the type range. If you have 16-bit integer which can store only (-32768 to 32767) than you must not put there 65535.

Answer (score 0):

I guess rotation of numbers takes place once we cross over the integer limit.
So once 65536 is reached, again the positive numbers start for greater values.

The original limit is -32768 to 32767. if we go to 32768, we have in fact reached -32768.So when we reach 65536, we get 0 and positive numbers start all over again